# 1064 - Syntax error near 'NUMBER NOT NULL default' 0.0 ',

Tags: mysql, sql

I cannot create a table with the SQL instructions below

I've tried to modify some de fault values but I have the same error.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CountryLanguage;
CREATE TABLE CountryLanguage (
  CountryCode TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  Lang TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  IsOfficial INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  Percentage NUMBER NOT NULL default '0.0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (CountryCode,Lang)
);
```

Table is not created and I have the message below:

```
Static analysis:

1 errors found during the scan.

Data type not recognized. (near "NUMBER" in position 164)

SQL request: CREATE TABLE CountryLanguage ( CountryCode TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '', Lang TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '', IsOfficial INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', Percentage NUMBER NOT NULL default '0.0', PRIMARY KEY (CountryCode,Lang) )

MySQL replied: Documentation
# 1064 - Syntax error near 'NUMBER NOT NULL default' 0.0 ',
   PRIMARY KEY (CountryCode, Lang)
) 'at line 5
```

Comment: Your question already contains the answer you are looking for: **Data type not recognized. (near "NUMBER" in position 164)**, the data type "NUMBER" does not exist: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: There is no number data type in mysql

Comment: This code is just wishful thinking. Consult the [documentation on MySQL column types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html) to absolve any mysteries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CountryLanguage;
CREATE TABLE CountryLanguage (
  CountryCode TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  Lang TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  IsOfficial INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  Percentage FLOAT NOT NULL default 0.0,
  PRIMARY KEY  (CountryCode,Lang)
);
```

Also, take care with your constant data - numbers don't have apostrophes round them (that's for strings)

Comment: I tried with your code it is OK. But I have now the error below:

**# 1170 - BLOB type 'CountryCode' column used in index definition without index length**

Comment: Do you really need 65 kilobytes to store a CountryCode (is it like.. `.de`? `.fr`?) and a Lang (like `en-US`?, `de-DE`?). Replace the `TEXT` with `VARCHAR(xx)` where `xx` is a number suitably minimally sized to hold the data you will store (like VARCHAR(5) for `en-US` or VARCHAR(2) for `de`, `fr`)

Comment: It is OK. I did **VARCHAR (3) for CountryCode**

But how can Idefine also well lang column? 
** # 1170 - BLOB type 'Lang' column used in index definition without index length**

Comment: Er.. the same way as you did countrycode! `Lang TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',` -> `Lang VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',`

Comment: [`DECIMAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html) is almost always preferable to `FLOAT`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CountryLanguage;

CREATE TABLE CountryLanguage (
    CountryCode char (3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    Language char (30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    IsOfficial INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    Percentage Decimal (4,1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0',
    PRIMARY KEY (CountryCode, Language)
);
```

or

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CountryLanguage;

CREATE TABLE CountryLanguage (
    CountryCode char (3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    Language char (30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    IsOfficial INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    Percentage Float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0',
    PRIMARY KEY (CountryCode, Language)
);
```